# Flex 4 - FileReference data returns null value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a **FileReference** to select image in my form. If I submit the form without selecting any image file, it will load another image programmatically.

My code:

```
        <s:Form id="mainForm" height="100%" width="100%" left="10%" right="10%" top="10%">
        <s:FormItem id="nameLabel" label="Employee Name">
            <s:TextInput id="employeeName" rollOver="validateAndSubmit()"/>
        </s:FormItem> 
        <s:FormItem id="imageLabel" label="Image">
            <mx:HBox>
                <s:TextInput id="employeeImageName" editable="false" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="false"/>
                <s:Button id="imageButton" label="Browse" click="onBrowseButtonClicked(event)"/>
            </mx:HBox >
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem>
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout gap="10"/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:Button id="submitButton" label="Submit" click="storeInputs(event)"/>
            <s:Button id="clearButton" label="clear" click="clearInputs()"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
    <s:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{arrayCollection}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" />
            <s:GridColumn headerText="Employee" id="imageColumn" dataField="imageData"/>
            <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:GridItemRenderer>                                    
                        <s:Image id="image"  source="{data.imageData}"  visible="true" height="80" width="100"/>
                    </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

ActionScript code like

```
    public var loadFile:FileReference; 
    [Bindable]private var arrayCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection ();

    private function onBrowseButtonClicked(event : MouseEvent) : void
    {
        loadFile = new FileReference();

        loadFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
        var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.gif; *.png");
        loadFile.browse([fileFilter]);
    }

    private function selectHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        loadFile.load();    
    }


        [Bindable]
        public var img:ByteArray;
        public function storeInputs(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (employeeImageName.text.length == 0)
            {
                loadFile = new FileReference();
                url = new URLRequest("http://localhost/images/male.jpg");
                    loadFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void
                    {
                        loadFile.upload(url);
                    });
              }
                img = loadFile.data;                
                arrayCollection.addItem({
                                 name : employeeName.text, 
                                 imageData: img
                                 });
        }
```

This code worked perfectly when I select an image file using the **Browse** button. But the **FileReference** data will return null data when I submit the form without selecting any image file. Anybody can find my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

may be this code help you...because in your code...complete event not called...when upload completed then only called...

```
if (employeeImageName.text.length == 0)
{
  loadFile =new FileReference();

  var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/images/male.jpg");

  loadFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void

  {
    img = loadFile.data;

  });

  loadFile.upload(url);

}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply...may be these 2 links help you...http://askjayvir.blogspot.in/2008/07/sample-flex-file-upload-application.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html